# Find the maximum possible value of $8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$,where $x>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

Find the maximum possible value of $8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$,where $x>0$

---

Let $P(x)=8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$
By using $AM-GM$ inequality on the first two terms give me
$8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}\geq2\sqrt{8\times 27\times(27\times 8)^{\log_6x}}\geq 12\sqrt{6x^3}$
$P(x)=8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3\geq12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$
I found the maximum value of $12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$ by differentiating and equating it to zero.I found that $12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$ is maximum at $x=6$.And its maximum value is $216$.
Can the maximum value of $12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$ be the maximum value of $P(x)?$I am confused because P(x)is greater than or equal to $12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$.$P(x)$ may be greater than the maximum value of $12\sqrt{6x^3}-x^3$.

Comment: which value did you found?

Comment: Why didnt you differentiate?

Comment: Directly the given equation

Comment: you are trying to find minimum value, but we need maximum value

Comment: is it $-x^3$ or $-2x^3$ at the end ?

Answer (score 3):

Angelo Mark has provided a good hint, but it seems that the OP needs more.

We can write
$$\begin{align}8\cdot 3^t+27\cdot 2^t-6^t&=8\cdot 3^t+27\cdot 2^t-2^t\cdot 3^t-8\cdot 27+8\cdot 27\\&=8(3^t-27)-2^t(3^t-27)+8\cdot 27\\&=(3^t-27)(8-2^t)+8\cdot 27\end{align}$$

Note here that $(3^t-27)(8-2^t)$ is non-positive.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $E=8(27)^{\log_{6}x}+27(8)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3=8(3^3)^{\log_{6}x}+27(2^3)^{\log_{6}x}-x^3$

$$=8(3)^{\log_{6}x^3}+27(2)^{\log_{6}x^3}-x^3$$

Now put $\log_{6}x^3=t$

$ \Rightarrow 6^t=x^3$

So we have that   $E=8(3)^{t}+27(2)^{t}-6^t$

Comment: How will we find the maximum value of this $8(3)^t+27(2)^t-(6)^t?$@AngeloMark